# javascript in iframe document.write overwrites parents document

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, document, document.write

I want to load HTML as string into an `iframe` via Javascript.
like this:

```
$('#iframe1').contents().find('html').html("<h1>This is an iframe</h1>");
```

this worked great until I found out, that inside this HTML upcomming Javascript like `document.write` are writing to the wrong document -> the parent!

Here is a Plunker to show it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YQAqqSDCVKnP3uhLj4lF?p=preview

if I load the same HTML to the `iframe` via src as external document, the `document.write` goes to the `iframe` (and not to the parent), which is what i was expecting.

Are there some insights out there? 
How can I tell the browser to correctly create the iframes document scope before it executes its Javascript?

---

PS: Its meant to be for preview purposes, so i inject HTML-Code of a (trusted!) source, but within that code, document.write is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. `srcdoc` is helpfull here.

```
$('#iframe1').attr({srcdoc:intrusiveHTML});
```

I updated the Plunker.

With `srcdoc`, Javascript won't slip up with the document scope.

It won't work in IE (http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc), so it might help to use Polyfill additionally: 
https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill

But I did not test that yet.

Comment: The srcdoc-polyfill seems to work nicely, even though it's not the only way to solve the problem, it's the one looking forwards, so good tip.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.write`, use `document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.write`.
Because when you point document it will take main window document, so we need to indicate which iframe doument need to be used.

Comment: its not me using document.write, its html-code from a third party - not under my control.